# Get output of Netcat in Pythonscript

Tags: python, shell, netcat

I need to get the output from netcat in python script.
My current code is

```
  response = subprocess.Popen(["netcat","smtp.myserver.net", "25"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
  x = response.find("220 ***")
```

I want it to check for 200 *** status and work with that, but it seems to wait for my input everytime it runs in a loop. How can I open netcat, get it's result, close it and move on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Don't do that.

Python has, built-in, an [smtp client library](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) that can do this trivially. Really. There's *no* reason not to use it.

```
from smtplib import SMTP
SMTP('smtp.myserver.net')
```

It's that simple. Catch the exceptions you care about.

#### If you *really* want to know what you were doing wrong,

Your program was waiting for you to type `quit`.

Solution? Close the writing-end first:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(["netcat","smtp.myserver.net", "25"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
child.stdin.close()
response = child.stdout.read()
x = response.find("220 ***")
```

The reason you need to do this is because *by default* standard input is still connecting `netcat` to your terminal.